# How do I set the default browser in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, .net, browser, visual-studio-setup

I don't have the stupid Browse With, and every time i figure out where it's out it only gives me options for Internet Explorer... It doesn't give me an option to change the browser... Strange enough I've already removed Internet Explorer from my PC... How is it still using it...

Comment: From VS .... go to Start >> Browse with..

Comment: Just because you've removed the IE Web browser product, it doesn't mean you've removed the MS Hosted Webbrowser Control. That's used in tons of products, so it really cannot be uninstalled.

Answer (score 4):

"Browse With" is still available

[image]

You should be able to select the browser you want from the next window, its self- explanatory.

Comment: https://imgur.com/qIY12Qm 
It's not available for me... I have Chrome installed I've tried hundreds of things but nothing works...

Comment: Have you opened a web project?

Comment: At this point I'm just trying to be able to use my C# app to edit the way a webpage looks on Google Chrome... but i'm not sure how

Comment: Also do you know anything about C++ and IDA66 and roblox exploit development? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49425975/c-roblox-exploit-development-offsets

Answer (score 2):

**Try this out**

1. First you have to install google chrome
2. Then go to visual studio and you can see a attach button with combo
   on the top of the window
3. Click the combo to select the browser
4. You can see a window of attach process
5. Their you can see a available processes grid and select the chrome
   browser

Answer (score 0):

Go To Project

1. ==> open folder
2. ==> select  file (ex: sample.aspx)
3. ==>left click
4. ==> select **Browse with**
5. ==>Select **Chrome**
6. ==>Click **Set As Default**

It works